# What's the difference between "on" and "for" in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between:

My brother's traveling to Argentina FOR business

and

My brother's flying to Argentina ON business?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on), meaning 8 of **on** is **engaged in**: that is the sense that would apply in this sentence. Here is one of the examples that they provide:

> Susan was called out of town **on** business.

Here is a typical reference:

> I went to New York City **on** business quite often back then. [In our image: Susan Alan (2009)](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=EyEzEJkMfiwC&pg=PA79&dq=%22city%20on%20business%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiks6TA_bPaAhXJrI8KHWRoAR4Q6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=%22city%20on%20business%22&f=false)

[Meaning 4](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for) for **for** is **Having (the thing mentioned) as a purpose or function**.

Here is a typical reference:

> Visitors coming to the city **for** business, combined with those attracted by the sights, soon made the tourist and convention industry second only to government. [Ottawa: An Illustrated History](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=IOhaBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&dq=%22city%20for%20business%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR1YGE_rPaAhUENY8KHd7QCL4Q6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=%22city%20for%20business%22&f=false)

Both are valid, though in my opinion **on business** is more common in spoken British English. The choice would depend on the speaker or writer's intended meaning: **on** means "engaged in", and **for** means "with the purpose of".

Answer (score 0):

I've seldom come across the second sentence. In fact, I doubt it's correct! When you use *'on business,'* it is generally...

> *'on business visa', 'on business trip...'* and so on...

So, for the given sentences, I think the first one sounds better.

> My brother is traveling to Argentina *for* business.

Then, your brother is *on a business trip (to Argentina).*

Answer (score 0):

**for business** can mean "intending to conduct business" or "looking to get business (e.g. customers)".

**for her business** could mean "representing her own company" or "on behalf of the company she works for".

**on business** would mean "engaged in or conducting business".

Thus, **for business** (without modifier) has a *prospective* sense. It would suggest that your mother might not actually have this Argentinian business yet.  Its meaning would be unclear without additional information.

Answer (score -2):

`For` is a temporal preposition  :

> My brother's traveling to Argentina for the first time.

`On` is a preposition of time, designating a future date.

> My brother's traveling to Argentina on Tuesday.

As is, neither of `my brother's traveling to Argentina FOR business` nor `my brother's traveling to Argentina ON business`, makes any sense to me.